# Using variables defined in one method inside another in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function like so: (and ps - I am new to ios development)

```
- (void)loadJSON
{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jamessuske.com/isthedomeopen/isthedomeopenGetData.php"];

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];

            NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            NSArray *firstItemArray = array[0];

            NSString *yesNoString = firstItemArray[0];
            NSString *dateString = firstItemArray[1];
            NSString *timeString = firstItemArray[2];
            NSString *homeString = firstItemArray[3];
            NSString *awayString = firstItemArray[4];
            NSString *lastUpdatedString = firstItemArray[5];
            NSString *previousIsOpen = firstItemArray[6];
            NSString *previousDate = firstItemArray[7];
            NSString *previousHome = firstItemArray[8];
            NSString *prviousHomeScore = firstItemArray[9];
            NSString *previousAway = firstItemArray[10];
            NSString *previousAwayScore = firstItemArray[11];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.YesOrNo.text = yesNoString;
                self.date.text = [@"For " stringByAppendingString:dateString];
                self.time.text = timeString;
                self.home.text = homeString;
                self.away.text = awayString;
                self.lastUpdated.text = lastUpdatedString;
                self.lastUpdatedText.text = @"Last Updated";
                self.vs.text = @"vs";
            });
        });
}
```

and I have all of those previous strings defined and I need to call those variables in my button action alert:

```
- (IBAction)PreviousResults:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *previousalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Previous Results" message: @previousIsOpen previousDate previousHome previousHomeScore previousAway previousAwayScore delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [previousalert show]; [previousalert release];
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not an Xcode question. And method names begin with a lowercase letter. And use instance variables.

Comment: When the user clicks the button PreviousResults, display an UIAlertView with a message that has variables that are defined in the loadJSON function

Comment: You can't, if you're talking about all those strings you defined -- those are local variables that won't be available outside that method. You need to make them ivars or properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define these variables in a more global scope, like in the interface file.

By defining the variables in the interface file (.h file), you will have access to it in any method of your implementation file. (.m file)

Answer (score 0):

Declare those variables in the .h class and then use those variables in the PreviousResults method . These variables are called as instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `NSArray` instance in this class. When you parse JSON data, you initialize that `NSArray`, and then you can use this `NSArray` instance in this class.